# Foreign keys constraints preventing creation of any new record in an empty DB

Tags: database, postgresql

I have this very simple DB in PostegreSQL made of the following tables:

- Agency
- Bank Account
- Subsidiary
- Person
- Owner

This is the logical scheme:

Agency (**id**, address, *subsidiary*)

Bank Account (**id**, *agency*)

Subsidiary (**id**, city, *head*)

Person (**id**, name, surname, *subsidiary*, *agency*)

Owner (**id**, ***bank account***)

In **bold** you can see the primary key for each table; in *italics* you can see the foreign keys, in particular:

- agency.subsidiary references subsidiary.id
- bank account.agency references agency.id
- subsidiary.head references person.id
- person.subsidiary references subsidiary.id
- person.agency references agency.id
- owner.bank account references bank account.id

The problem is that, if I suppose to start with a clean DB with those tables, not a single new record can be inserted because of the foreign keys constraints!

For example, if I want to create a new subsidiary, I must already have a record in Person which has not already been set as head of another subsidiary.

Same thing happens if I want to create a new person to appoint as head of a new subsidiary I want to create soon after. Not possible, because I need pre-existing records in subsidiary and agency.

And the list goes on for the other tables.

One solution is allowing null values on foreign keys for each table but in this case, for example, I could create a subsidiary with no head (it's acceptable because it's just been made). But in this case then I'll need another operation in my web app specifically to appoint a person to a newly created subsidiary.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Refer to the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set-constraints.html  Tip: `SET CONSTRAINT ALL DEFERRED` + autoCommit must be disabled

Comment: Hi NoobNe0 Should Agency and subsidiary have a circular reference?  if you removed the subsidiary to agency link Or create another table (Link table) Eg a Agency MAYBE be a subsidiary you have a link table? Then you could fill 1) Agency 2) Bank account 3) Person 4)subsidiary 5) Owner. You Might like to look at Database normalization Ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization  Hope this helps